# Unexpected Nullable Found after left join

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm having some litte trouble developing a web application with Play! framework, Scala and Anorm with Mysql.

I have these two case classes :

```
case class Supplier(id : Pk[Long]= NotAssigned,
         identityId : Option[SupplierIdentity], 
         addressId : Option[Address], userId : User) {}

object Supplier {
      val simple = {
        get[Pk[Long]]("Supplier.id") ~
        SupplierIdentity.simple ~
        Address.simple ~
        User.simple map {
          case id ~ identityId ~ addressId~ userId => 
               Supplier(id, Some(identityId), Some(addressId), userId)
        }
```

and

```
case class Address(id : Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, via : String, cap : Int, comune : String, provincia : String, paese : String) {

}

object Address {

    val simple = {
            get[Pk[Long]]("Address.id") ~
            get[String]("Address.via") ~
            get[Int]("Address.cap") ~
            get[String]("Address.comune") ~
            get[String]("Address.provincia") ~
            get[String]("Address.paese") map {
            case id ~ via ~ cap ~ comune ~ provincia ~ paese=> 
            Address(id, via ,cap , comune , provincia , paese)
            }
    }
```

And I have this query to acces my database while trying to retrive a Supplier :

```
def findByIdentity(identityId: Long) : Option[Supplier]= {
      DB.withConnection {implicit connetion =>
      SQL("""SELECT * 
          FROM Supplier 
          LEFT JOIN SupplierIdentity 
          ON Supplier.identity_id= SupplierIdentity.id  
          LEFT OUTER JOIN Address
          ON Supplier.address_id= Address.id   
          LEFT JOIN User 
          ON Supplier.user_id= User.id 
          WHERE Supplier.identity_id={id}""").on('id->identityId).as(Supplier.simple.singleOpt)
    }
   }
```

And I'm sure that it works because I've tryed on Mysql server and it works with the right values :

```
id | identity_id | address_id | user_id | id   | supplier_code | type | ragione_sociale | partita_iva | is_production | id   | via  | cap  | comune | provincia | paese | id   | name    |
+----+-------------+------------+---------+------+---------------+------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+------+------+------+--------+-----------+-------+------+---------+
|  2 |           2 |       NULL |       1 |    2 |             1 | q    | q               |           1 |             1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL   | NULL      | NULL  |    1 | Tiziano |
```

But when I try to use this method from My controller I get This error :

> [RuntimeException:
>   UnexpectedNullableFound(ColumnName(Address.id,Some(id)))]

And here is my problem because those column could be at null, but I can't find a way to handle the null value. I would like the wuery to works, even if some of its column are at null. 
Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using left joins, the parsers should be optional, like so:

```
case class Supplier(id : Pk[Long]= NotAssigned,
     identityId : Option[SupplierIdentity], 
     addressId : Option[Address], userId : User) {}

object Supplier {
  val simple = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("Supplier.id") ~
    (SupplierIdentity.simple ?) ~
    (Address.simple ?) ~
    (User.simple ?) map {
      case id ~ identityId ~ addressId~ userId => 
           Supplier(id, identityId, addressId, userId)
}
```

It seems like `userId` should be `Option[User]` as well, because you're left joining. If it's not optional, it should be an inner join (with the original parser), otherwise you'll get the same problem. The reason why this occurs is the left join keeps all those null columns, but your parser is looking for non-null values. `Address.simple ?` will parse as `Option[Address]`, and be `None` when it can't find the entire model.

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Just for correction, if someone has the same problem, you have to remove "some" from Supplier(id, Some(identityId), Some(addressId), userId), so it became Supplier(id, identityId, addressId, userId) and it works perfectly. And you're right LimbSoup, user will be implemented in the same way (but I don't care for now)

Comment: Right. Just overlooked that.